# How to integrate screenshots in allure report with webdriverIO

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver-io, allure

I'm trying to generate screenshots in my allure reports after each step in my test or just a single screenshot at the end of the test. I have referred to the webdriverIO docs and it seems I should use `afterStep` function together with the `.takeScreenshot` method. I have tried that in my config file but no screenshot is taken
Here is my afterStep function:

```
afterStep: function (test, scenario, { error, duration, passed }) {
 if (!error) {
     browser.takeScreenshot() } }
```

The closest I have come to my desired result is by using this

```
 afterTest: function (test, scenario, { error, duration, passed }) { 
if (!error) { 
    browser.saveScreenshot('test.png') } }
```

What it does is take a screenshot at the end of the test and store it in my root directory,

[image]

the image however cannot be displayed on Allure Report

[image]

How do I attach screenshots to be shown on the Allure Report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of scrutiny on my code, I realized that I was doing one thing wrong here.

I had another `afterTest` hook in my config file which was being called instead of the hook to capture the screenshot. To solve this, I used a `browser.takeScreenshot()` function to the original `afterTest` hook and this solves my problem. The screenshot is attached at the end of the allure report.

`browser.saveScreenshot` saves the screenshot to your local folder while `browser.takeScreenshot` attaches it to the allure report.

My full `afterTest` hook

```
afterTest: async function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
        if(passed) {
          await browser.takeScreenshot();
          browser.executeScript('browserstack_executor: {"action": "setSessionStatus", "arguments": {"status":"passed","reason": "Assertions passed"}}');
        } else {
          browser.executeScript('browserstack_executor: {"action": "setSessionStatus", "arguments": {"status":"failed","reason": "At least 1 assertion failed"}}');
        }
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having only 1 `afterTest` command on my `wdio.conf.ts` file.

I'm using ts and I have to add async & await , and after this it get solved  and attaching the screenshot in the allure report:

```
 afterTest: async function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
            if (error) {
                await browser.takeScreenshot()
              }
        },
```